# Link not correctly showing up in Google Chrome

Tags: html, webkit

I have an  tag on my page that looks something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="doAFunction(1, 2);">Do something</a>
```

But in Chrome, the link doesn't show as a link, just text. However, it's clickable and works fine. Should I have a class for this, or is my code incorrect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no problem which is likely to cause a display error ... "void" should have a parameter specified methinks, but that wouldn't cause a display issue.

Try right clicking on it (in chrome) and selecting Inspect Element, that'll show you the styles that are being applied to it.  You can then hopefully track down whether or not your link styles are being applied, and what might be overriding it.

PS. if you can post us a link to an example, we can probably identify the cause pretty quickly.  We're good like that :P

Comment: Yeah, it turns out I forgot to close a span tag I had opened earlier. Thanks anyway. :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="doAFunction(1, 2); return false;">Do something</a>
```

Comment: Nope, that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="javascript:doAFunction(1, 2);">Do something</a>
```